# Why are point discontinuities not differentiable?

Tags: limits, derivatives

I know that the derivative exists when the two sided limit at one point exists and  at most of the discontinuities the two sided limit doesn't exist.
But at point discontinuities, the two sided limit does exist, right?
So it should have a derivative, i.e. it should be differentiable.

But I read some of the answers for similar past questions and they say the derivate doesn't exist. Where am i wrong?

Comment: Do you know the theorem that states that if $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then $f$ must be continuous at $a$?

Comment: What are point discontinuities?

Comment: The limits do *not* in fact exist.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Removable discontinuities.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, it states that if $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)= f(a)$, then it is continuous,. But why?

Comment: Because one *proves* that this is the case... which part of the proof are you unsure of?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I understand what you are saying, and I think I understand the theorem, but my question why doesn't the limit exist even if the one sided limits seem equal, and subsequently why doesn't the derivative exist?

Comment: The one sided limits of *which limit*? For differentiability, you consider $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$. What makes you think the one sided limits of **that** limit "seem equal"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You clarify in the comment that you are talking about points $a$ where
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$$
exists, but does not equal $f(a)$.

The thing is that you seem to have lost sight of *which* limit needs to exist for the function to be differentiable at $a$. It's not the above limit, but rather
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}.\tag{1}$$
Does that limit exist when $f$ has a removable discontinuity at $a$?

Well, clearly if $f$ is not even defined at $a$, then (1) does not even make sense, let alone exist. So we must assume that $f(a)$ exists, but does not equal
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L.\tag{2}$$
Let us note that (2) is the same as:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h) = L\tag{3}$$

Now let's look at what happens to (1) when this is the case. Because $f(a)\neq L$, then $L-f(a)\neq 0$. We have:
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-L + L-f(a)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\bigl(f(a+h)-L\bigr) + \bigl(L-f(a)\bigr)}{h}.
\end{align*}$$
Now consider the numerator: note that while $f(a+h)-L$ approaches $0$ as $h\to 0$, the quantity $L-f(a)$ is a nonzero quantity. That means that the numerator approaches the nonzero quantity $L-f(a)$, while the denominator goes to $0$. That means that this limit *does not exist*: this is one of the limit laws: if $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exists and is not zero, and $\lim_{x\to a}h(x)=0$, then $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$ does not exist. Here, the limit will be $\infty$ or $-\infty$ on each side, depending on whether $L-f(a)\gt 0$ or $L-f(a)\lt 0$. The limit certainly does not exist.

So the function is not differentiable at $a$, because the limit (1) does not exist.

Comment: Got it! I was confused between $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ and $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ and mixed up the derivative at that point with the two sided limit at that point. This was great. Thanks!

Comment: But, why then does the limit need to exist for the point to have a derivative?(if you don't mind me asking another question)

Comment: @ATS: That's the **definition**: the function $f$ has a derivative at $a$ if and only if the limit $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ exists, and in that case, the derivative *is* the value of the limit.

Comment: No, the $/lim_{x\to a} f(x)$. It needs to exist for a derivative to exist at $a$, right?

Comment: @ATS If it does not exist, then neither does $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$, because the numerator does not approach $0$ while the denominator does.

Comment: I didn't understand that, maybe I should start from the basics? Thank you though.

Comment: @ATS: Arturo is saying: yes, we do need the limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ to exist for the derivative at $a$ to exist. For if this limit did not exist, then the limit $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ would also not exist. (This is one way to prove that differentiability implies continuity (i.e. continuity is a necessary condition for differentiability). The other is to note that if $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ exists, then $$\lim_{h\to 0}\bigl(f(a+h)-f(a)\bigr)=\left(\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}\right)\times\lim_{h\to 0}h=0,$$using the product law for limits.)

Comment: @Joe $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ won't exist if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ doesn't exist because $f(a) = \lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ right?

Comment: @ATS: Your comment doesn't really make sense to me. If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ doesn't exist, then it certainly isn't equal to $f(a)$. The following conditions are *necessary* (but not *sufficient*) for $f$ to be differentiable at $a$: (i) $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists, and (ii) $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$. (My above comment was a little imprecise: noting that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ has to exist for the derivative at $a$ to exist is not enough to show that differentiability implies continuity. We need to show that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists *and* equals $f(a)$ in order for the derivative to exist.)

Comment: @ATS: Anyway, if $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ won't exist if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ doesn't exist for the following reason: there is a theorem which states that if $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists (in $\mathbb R$), and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=0$, then it must be the case that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$

Comment: Okay great, thanks! In my previous comment I meant that since in order to continuous we need $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ equal to $f(a)$ so if the former doesn't exist latter will also not exist and hence the derivative wont exist. @Joe